# my iphone app was rejected due to microphone perssion issue

Tags: iphone, permissions, ios7, avaudiosession

In my app i am capturing picture by using AVCaptureStillImageOutput class.
This method also use AVCaptureSession class which is now by default use AVAudioSession

*ref: Apple doc "AVCaptureSession now uses your app’s AVAudioSession by default"*

due to AVAudioSession class when i try to capture pic, iOS7 generates a permission request for access microphone of device but i am not recording video i am capturing still image that's why apple review team found my app has not such feature which use microphone

HOW to fix this issue ? i want my app not use microphone.

**Apple review team remarks:**
     During review we were prompted to provide consent to use the microphone, however, we were not able to find any features or functionality that use the microphone for audio recording.

The Camera feature did not include recording functionality nor are there any other relevant features found at the time of review.

The microphone consent request is generated by the use of either AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord audio categories.

If you do not intend to record audio with your application, it would be appropriate to choose the AVAudioSession session category that fits your application's requirements or modify your app to include audio-recording features.

Comment: not same like that i also add some more code ad checks
the complete answer i will post soon right now i am busy in project.
but your direct me on right way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set your capture device the right one?

Something like:

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

It's hard to know without some code.